# Default network setting of windows defender firewall

Tags: windows-firewall

[image]

Since public networks is not recommended, why is it always the default choice on my PC? I'm using it at home.

Comment: Were you connected to a public network at the time that it came up? Check if your network profile is not public.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @harrymc No I'm using it in my home

Comment: [Check if your network profile is not public](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you I see! it was set to public network for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default network option is the one you are using.
As the user's home network profile was set to Public, the default
setting was Public. It was fixed by setting the network to Private.

See Microsoft's
[Make a Wi-Fi network public or private in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d).

Comment: +1. Nice answer